# generate serialVersionUID automatically in intellij stopped working

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-warnings, serialversionuid

I've managed before to generate serialVersionUID automatically in IntelliJ IDEA by both installing the plugin GenerateSerialVersionUID and enabling the checkbox in settings - code - inspection like prior answers to this questions said. I can't let this go, anyone? I have EE 2016.1.3. I've tried all the answers here. What I'm after is the warning, i.e IntelliJ lets me know that I should provide serialVersionUID. Generate it is bonus.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the warning by going to

> Settings → Editor → Inspections → Java → Serializable class
>   without SerialVersionUID

[image]

Then, when this is enabled, you can generate missing SerialVersionUID by clicking on the lightbulb icon (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>). Is is generated for you automatically. You do not need any plugins for that. If it is still not working you may try to uninstall your plugin as it may interfere with built-in functionality.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer..As I said this was the first thing I tried and it worked. Now it doesn't and I've tried with and without plugin....

Comment: Is the class actually implementing serializable? Are there any other plugins which may interfere with inspections? Don't you have inspections off in general or power-saving mode on? Did you try "Invalidate Caches and restart?"

Comment: Yes, no, no and yes. But thank you all for your answers. When I checked the box in inspections I found it by searching and the box I checked was not under Java, but AndroidLint.. So now it's working!

Comment: Glad it worked. In that case you might want to accept the answer as it is the preferred way to configure the inspection for users who come here with simliar problem. Thanks.

Comment: For IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1. EAP (Ultimate), it's under "JVM Language" setting, not under "Java"; hope this helps someone with the same version.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Vu Nguyen here in the comments, for IDEA 2022.1 (Community and Ultimate versions) the warning can be enabled at:

> Settings → Editor → Inspections → JVM Language → Serializable class without SerialVersionUID

Or simply use the search option:

1. press **CTRL + SHIFT + A**
2. write/paste: "**Serializable class without SerialVersionUID**"